# can you make a vm run natively on a new system

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, vmware

I got a new computer and was wondering if I could transfer my vmWare Ubuntu VM and all of its adjusted settings from my main computer so that it runs natively on the new computer?

So I can free up a good chunk of my main computer's memory and speed it up quite a bit. Without having to go back and figure out how I tweaked each kernel(also I won't have snapshot so I don't feel comfortable going in as root in case I severely mess stuff up).

I was hoping I could format the VM onto a thumb drive and somehow do a boot install with it.

Bonus points if you use small words bc I'm familiar with Linux but not a expert by any means!

Comment: VMware uses the term `V2P` (Virtual to Physical).  An Internet search will find a number of guides on how to do V2P.

Answer (score 0):

I've had good luck with mondo archive. It will create a set of bootable isos to backup & restore whatever system. The only thing it may have trouble with going from virtual to physical is if the kernel is missing any drivers that will be needed on the new hardware which were not included in the old Hardware. For instance if you have a special raid card or maybe a different processor and chipset. You can manually load those in your existing kernel using kmod. The best way to check for one of those is just to do a base install on the new system and find out which kernel modules you need to install on the old system before doing the copy.

Answer (score -1):

You could use something like CloneZilla, make a clone of the virtual machine and then restore it on your new machine.

Comment: One answer a question please - and generally more information on the process of using the software is nice - [this is our preferred way of doing answers that recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers)